# How do I dynamically create a json file from an html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

EDIT: Apologies for the partially duplicate question. I seem to have missed it.

I've written a function to scan a table I'd like it to use the header as a property name and add it to an empty object. The problem seems to be with the json object. I have tried all manner of syntax that I have been able to find and haven't been able to add properties to the object.

```html
var jsonData = [{}];

function saveTableToDataSet(tableName,jsonObj) {
 debugger;
 var oTable = document.getElementById(tableName);
    var columnNames = []
 var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
    //get column names
    var oCells = oTable.rows.item(0).cells;
    var cellLength = oCells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cellLength; i++) {
        var cellVal = oCells.item(i).innerHTML;
        columnNames[i] = cellVal;
    }
    //get column data
 for (var j = 1; j < rowLength; j++) {
  var oCells = oTable.rows.item(j).cells;
        var cellLength = oCells.length;
        for (var k = 0; k < cellLength; k++) {
            var columnName = columnNames[k];
   var cellVal = oCells.item(k).innerHTML;

   //the problem
   jsonObj[j.columnName] = cellVal;
   }
  }
 }
};
```

I'm obviously not referencing the object or its properties correctly but I have tried infinite combinations of syntax. All except the correct one seemingly.

EDIT: It's just seeing my jsonObj parameter as a string. I've changed the last bit to:

```html
  //the problem 
  newObj = []; 
  newObj[columnName] = cellVal; 
  jsonData["dataItem"+j] = newObj; 
}
```

And it's working. Ideally though I'd like to be able to pass the name of the object in.

Comment: How do you call this function? Is the jsonData what is passed to it?

Comment: At the moment its OnCientClick and I pass the table name and json object name in as arguments:

OnClientClick="saveTableToDataSet('seriesData','jsonData');"

Comment: The reason it sees your jsonObj as a string is because you pass the variable in with quotes around it

Comment: Wow I feel dumb right now! Thanks. New to js, json and chartsjs so overthinking everything today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your call to this:

```
OnClientClick="saveTableToDataSet('seriesData', jsonData);"
```

Removing the single quotes will treat `jsonData` as a variable instead of a literal.